# Xbee simple communication using Python?

Tags: xbee

As a part of my project I am using [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee). I want sample Python code to make two XBees to communicate with each other in Windows. I have written code, but it has a problem.

What would like to sent a message like "hello" from one XBee, and it should be printed on the other XBee side. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the great [python-xbee](http://code.google.com/p/python-xbee/) library, and Digi's [examples.digi.com](http://examples.digi.com/) as two excellent resources for someone new to the XBee.  Between those two sites, you should be able to get your XBee radios joined to each other (using the second link) and then get them working in Python (with the first link).

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything else you have to configure the devices, use XCTU software:

First device - **Coordinator API mode**: 
 - ID 7777(or any random value)
 - DL set to FFFF

Second device - **Router AT mode**: 
 - ID 7777(has to be the same for every device)
 - DL set to 0

Code for coordinator (listen mode):

```
import serial 
import time
from xbee import ZigBee

PORT = "COM1" #change the port if you are not using Windows to whatever port you are using
BAUD_RATE = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

# Create API object

xbee = ZigBee(ser)

# Continuously read and print packets
while True:
    try:
        response = xbee.wait_read_frame()

        print("\nPacket received at %s : %s" %(time.time(), response))

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ser.close()
        break
```

Code for the remote device:

```
import serial

PORT = "COM1" #change the port if you are not using Windows to whatever port you are using
BAUD_RATE = 9600
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

while True:
try:
    data = raw_input("Send:")
    ser.write(data) #if you are using python 3 replace data with data.encode()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ser.close()
    break
```

Run the code and send data from the remote device to the coordinator. You will be able to see the packets printed in the console and in the rx_data field will be the payload.

I hope this is helpful.